# Extending User Model Django Oscar?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I want to add fields in User Model so I extended it by making a new app `extended_profile`.
My Models.py :

```
from oscar.apps.customer.abstract_models import AbstractUser    
class Profile(AbstractUser):

        nickname =  models.CharField(_("Nick Name"), max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
        flavor = models.CharField(max_length=2, verbose_name="Flavor")
        avatar = models.CharField(max_length=3, verbose_name="Avatar")
        send_newsletter = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Send Newsletter")
```

Settings.py I mention the new model 
`AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'extended_profile.Profile'`

Now When I access Partner Models

```
>>> from forked_apps.partner.models import *
>>> p = Partner.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> p.users.all()
```

I am getting the following error.

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/partner/partner/add/
column partner_partner_users.profile_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "partner_partner_users"."profile_id" FROM "partner_pa...
               ^
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/partner/partner/add/
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
column partner_partner_users.profile_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "partner_partner_users"."profile_id" FROM "partner_pa...
               ^
```

The partner model has a users field which has a many to many relationship with the profile model.

```
class Partner(models.Model):
        ....
        users = models.ManyToManyField(
        AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="partners",
        blank=True, verbose_name=_("Users"))
```

According to error `profile_id` field doesn't exist. Profile model will have a `Id` field by default ? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: What statement do u use to call that query?

Comment: Not able to read any partner class object from admin or shell. Not able to add any partner class object .

Comment: What error do you get when you try accessing partner class object? That might be useful if you share it

Comment: shared in the question body `column partner_partner_users.profile_id does not exist`

Comment: Put the python code where you get the error

Comment: added in the question body

Comment: Did you create and run migrations?